# Why does perl crash with "*** glibc detected *** perl: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer"?

Tags: perl, pointers, glibc

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.012;
use XML::LibXML::Reader; 

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new( location => 'http://www.heise.de/' ) or die $!;

while ( $reader->read ) {
    say $reader->name;
}
```

At the end of the output from this script I get this error-messages:

> *** glibc detected *** perl: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000b362e0 ***
>   ======= Backtrace: =========
>   /lib64/libc.so.6[0x7fb84952fc76]
>   ...
>   ======= Memory map: ========
>   00400000-0053d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 182002                             /usr/local/bin/perl
>   ...

Is this due a bug?

perl -V:

Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 12 subversion 0) configuration:

Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=2.6.31.12-0.2-desktop, archname=x86_64-linux
    uname='linux linux1 2.6.31.12-0.2-desktop #1 smp preempt 2010-03-16 21:25:39 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 gnulinux '
    config_args='-Dnoextensions=ODBM_File'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=undef, usemultiplicity=undef
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
    optimize='-O2',
    cppflags='-fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.4.1 [gcc-4_4-branch revision 150839]', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc', ldflags =' -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /lib /usr/lib /lib64 /usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib64
    libs=-lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
    perllibs=-lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc
    libc=/lib/libc-2.10.1.so, so=so, useshrplib=false, libperl=libperl.a
    gnulibc_version='2.10.1'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-Wl,-E'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC', lddlflags='-shared -O2 -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector'

Characteristics of this binary (from libperl):
  Compile-time options: PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV PERL_MALLOC_WRAP USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_LARGE_FILES USE_PERLIO
                        USE_PERL_ATOF
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Apr 15 2010 13:25:46
  @INC:
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.0/x86_64-linux
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.0
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.12.0/x86_64-linux
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.12.0
    .

Comment: hope this helps you "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244822/glibc-detected-error"

Comment: When you have these sorts of problems, specify the platform, the version of perl, the source of perl (package, self compiled, etc), and the compilation details. That's probably easiest with just showing us the output of `perl -V`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope, this [Debian Bug report #479698](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=479698) is answer of your question.

Comment: Fixed in version perl/5.10.0-11.1 but I use perl 5.12
I changed something in my script and now I don't get this message any more.

Comment: Not really. That was a double free with **SVN::_Repos**.
This is a double free in **XML::LibXML**.